# Defining a pointer to an OpenGL Vertex Array Object

Tags: opengl

Consider the following OpenGL code snippet:

```
GLuint vao;
glCreateVertexArrays(1, glBindVertexArray(&vao));
```

I'm under the impression that what this code does is

1. Creates a pointer, of type `GLuint`, that will eventually point to an OpenGL Vertex Array Object. The name of this pointer is `vao`.
2. Indirectly allocates memory *through OpenGL* for the actual Vertex Array Object (i.e., no use of `malloc` in C or `new` in C++). The way that this is done is through the function `glCreateVertexArrays`. This function also makes the pointer `vao` point to the Vertex Array Object.

Is my understanding correct? If so, in (1), why is the type of the pointer `GLuint` and not explicitly defined as a pointer type (for example with `*` in C/C++ or with the OpenGL type `GLintptr`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is invalid, `glBindVertexArray` returns `void` so you cannot pass its return value as a parameter to `glCreateVertexArrays`, because there is none.

The correct way to create a VAO, as per OpenGL 4.5 profile, is:

```
GLuint vao;
glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao);
```

As per the meaning of `vao` and why its type is `GLuint`: it is *not* a pointer. It is an opaque value that is used internally to locate the VAO inside the OpenGL implementation tables. The driver may allocate memory on both, the CPU and/or GPU for storing the state associated with the VAO. It is a complex state with quite a lot of book-keeping, which is much more involved than `malloc` or `new`. (In particular `malloc` can't be used to allocate GPU memory.)

Comment: So I should think of `vao` as something like an (unsigned integer) key in a hash table lookup (that can get me to a vertex array object)?

Comment: @George: Pretty much. That's how all [OpenGL Objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object) work.